# Why can't you see meteors, but you can see comets from the moon?

Tags: astronomy, moon, meteors, comets

Why can't you see meteors from the moon and why can you see comets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard answer on Earth is that meteors are seen only when meteoroids enter the Earth's atmosphere and heat it to incandescence, while comets are bodies in interplanetary space, visible from anywhere in the solar system. On the Moon, there is no significant atmosphere, so there are no meteors as such. However, meteors *have* been observed (from Earth) on several occasions impacting the *surface* of the Moon, so in fact meteors *have* been seen on the Moon.

http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2001/ast30nov_1/

Comment: I don't see how this is any more complete than the other answer.

Answer (score 9):

The Moon has no atmosphere, so meteors would not heat up and glow as they descended, as they do on Earth. Comets, however, reflect light from the Sun, and thus can be seen from any sufficiently dark location.